# Inject a div with content script not working

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm stuck with what seems to be really simple.
I'm trying to inject a div of my own in every page the user visited, in a google chrome extention.
I looked at examples on the web, but nothing seems to be working with me :s

Here's my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "My extension",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*", "tabs", "https://*/*"
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "My extension",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["test.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
  }
]
}
```

And my test.js

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
newdiv.setAttribute('id','this_is_my_own_div');
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

But I get nothing in source codes...
My div's not created.
How can I check if my test.js is running ? I can't understand why it is working with others and not with me :s
Any help appreciate !

Answer (score 2):

It worked try:

```
"browser_action": { "default_title": "My extension", "default_icon": "icon.png" },
```

instead of:

```
"browser_action": { "name": "My extension", "icons": ["icon.png"] },
```

Comment: It worked try "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "My extension",
 "default_icon": "icon.png"
}, instead of "browser_action": {
    "name": "My extension",
    "icons": ["icon.png"]
},

Comment: I might be missing someting here... That doesn't work either. Stil no "this_is_my_own_div" in the source page of http://www.amazon.com/ for example...

Comment: Hmm, apparently, it's working on my colleague's Mac. I run Version 23.0.1271.64 m on Windows 8, maybe this is why... Strange though...